# Why are my CSS changes not being displayed on my website?

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of creating a portfolio website for a web design course I am taking. I have created a style sheet for my website but I am having trouble getting the changes to show up on my site. All of the changes appear when I view it locally through Chrome, but when I upload my website the changes don't show up. I have checked my code and even tried validator.nu to see if their are any problems but it appears that their are none.

Here are my html and css files:

https://gist.github.com/J-Conley/94255b04292287b58892b75fdc5e35c0

and my website:

http://cook-camel-58438.bitballoon.com/.

If it helps I have a folder called cf_template-1.1.1 and in that folder I have a folders named html, css, and img. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. The browser doesn't load the changes because it gets the css file from it's cache. Clear it and try again.

Comment: Open your chrome browser and your website, right click on your page and open the dev console (inspect). Click in the top right corner on the triple points -> Settings. Under the Network group activate: "Disable Cache (while DevTools is open). Refresh your site while dev tools are open. Just to verify its no cache problem.

Comment: If you view the source of your website, your external stylesheet seems to be  an empty JavaScript file hosted on CloudFront, rather than a valid CSS file. Copy and paste error?

Comment: Your css files are somehow loaded from a js: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/bundles/adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc.js">` and not like in your github file

Comment: Did you declare your css inside the index file because i didn't find any style-sheet path....!!!

Comment: I think this is on browser's cache, try pressing ctrl+F5 :)

Comment: If this no happen, try double check the path of the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in the console, make sure to fix these and try again if it persist.
[image]

- the image urls behaves differently in localhost and live, make sure to upload those images properly using your website builder whatever it is and not use static urls.
- I see you used bootstrap here. When overriding styles make sure you use the exact same selector whatever library did used you are trying to modify i.e. `.md-content .md-container .md-input .md-label span` you can use inspect element / web developer tools to find this and use the exact same selector to override the default style given by the library, make sure the last thing you import is your custom style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You made wrong with css file path.

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template go here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
```

Replace With

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template go here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: Your sure his folder structure is like this. I think it is more something like `../css/styles.css`

Answer (score 0):

all your images are not found. Check the path / upload them again and make sure it's right. Maybe try the absolute path;

http://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/bundles/adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc.js is **not** a style sheet. Please remove the style tag of it

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your Jquery from version 1.11.3 to 3x. 
That will help because version 1.11.3 is not compatible with Bootstrap 3.3.5. 
Also you should try to press the "disable cache" button in `Chrome Dev Tools->Network->Disable Cache`. Usually, cache is the culprit of not updating CSS.